# Why Does Litecoin Transaction Show Zero Confirmations for last 3 hours

Tags: blockchain, litecoin

I tried sending 193.09 LTC from my mobile wallet. There wasn't an option for how much of a fee to add to the transaction, so I just sent as is. It took a long time to send from my phone and then once it processed from my mobile wallet it just sat (and as of now still is) on the blockchain unconfirmed. I'm a relative noob to Litecoin, but I know that BTC and ETH won't even let you trade unless you attach the right amount of fees or gas, so I thought my transaction should go through just fine.

My question is, will this eventually go though?

Do I have any options to remedy this? Or is it just a matter of time before it gets confirmed?

Hash ID can be seen here:

http://ltc.blockr.io/tx/info/280589ea1fefd39bb05723cf9c3f92e12e12bd7b1d7b6c6e84fa6b4ff63e97aa

If there's any other relevant info needed to diagnose I'll gladly provide. Thanks in advance!